# Puppet creates a broken symlink

Tags: puppet

For example I have a symlink `/etc/foo/folder11/some/link.txt` which points to `etc/foo/folder12/some/file.txt`.
And in puppet I have the following

```
ensure_resource('file', "/etc/bar/link.txt", {
  owner  => $someUser,
  mode   => '0444',
  source => `/etc/foo/folder11/some/link.txt`,
})
```

After puppet run it creates a broken symlink `/etc/bar/link.txt` which points to `../../folder12/some/file.txt`.
Why does it create so strange symlink? And how can I force puppet to create `/etc/foo/link.txt` symlink which should point to the same file to which `/etc/foo/folder11/some/link.txt` points to ?

Note that I don't use `ensure => link` because sometimes `/etc/foo/folder11/some/link.txt` may be a regular file and in this case `/etc/bar/link.txt` should be a copy of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was in `/etc/foo/folder11/some/link.txt` which was a relative symlink. I changed it to be absolute and now it works fine.